# getchar() in C with while looping not printing afterwards

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, getchar

I don't understand why the `printf()` call after the `while` loop does not get executed?

```
int main(){
    while((getchar()) != EOF){
        characters ++;
        if (getchar() == '\n'){
            lines++;
        }
    }
    printf("lines:%8d\n",lines);
    printf("Chars:%8d",characters);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you  do some debugging of your code. Either simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or actually step through the code in a debugger. How many times do you read characters from the input in the loop?

Comment: Think about the number of times `getchar()` is called in each loop iteration (hint: don't disregard the execution in the `while` test expression).

Comment: How do you create the `EOF`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do that

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int characters=0,lines=0;
    char ch;

    while((ch=getchar())!= EOF)
    {

        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
        else
        {
            characters++;
            while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&&ch!=EOF);   //is to remove \n after a character
        }
    }

    printf("lines:%8d\n",lines);
    printf("Chars:%8d",characters);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a
s
d
f

^Z
lines:       1
Chars:       4
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 8.654 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Note: ^Z(ctrl+z) is to send EOF to stdin (in windows)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful of you're treatment in the `while` loop. Indeed, you are missing every caracter read in your while statement. You have to save this input, in order to use it afterwards. 
The proper syntax would be `while(( c = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: Thanks for the helping! Btw just way to know that how do you exit the EOF properly? when i type the input for getchar() and exit with ctr + D, the prinf funtion just gone and print nothing for me

Comment: Are you sure that your file has a proper ```EOF``` ?

Comment: I was testing the type input that i am directly typing the input instead of inserting a file input, will that be the reason why this isn't working out?

Comment: The ```EOF``` special caracter is only defined at the end of a file. If your want to proper test your programm, you have to call the ```open()``` function, and work with the real file.

Comment: @cocool97 your last comment is wrong: under Windows you can use Ctrl+Z to generate EOF, under Linux it's Ctrl+D. And also wrong because you'd not open the file with `open` but with `fopen`.

Comment: @BrianZhang your first comment is a candidate for another question.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int characters = 0;
  int lines = 0;
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    characters++;
    if (c == '\n') {
      lines++;
      characters--;  // ignore \n
    }
  }
  printf("lines: %8d\n", lines);
  printf("Chars: %8d", characters);

  return 0;
}
```

`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` might look a bit confusing.

Basically it calls `getchar`, puts the returned valuee into `c` ands then checks if `c` equals `EOF`.